# VBA to save multiple ranges in single excel sheet as pdf based on ranges mentioned in Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, range, cell

I am new to VBA and would request your help in saving a single excel sheet with multiple ranges as a pdf file. My excel sheet has multiple ranges in Sheet1 e.g. $B$1:$X$45, $B$91:$X$135, $B$181:$X$225 etc. which need to be exported into a pdf file.

Based on data available in the ranges, I have defined the ranges to be printed/saved as pdf in a single cell i.e. H5 in Sheet2 in this format $B$1:$X$45, $B$91:$X$135, $B$181:$X$225 one after the other using concatenate function. The number of ranges to be printed based on data available in Sheet1 may vary between 25 to 40 and these ranges to be printed/saved as pdf are updated based on formula in a single cell i.e. H5 in Sheet2.

Would request help in VBA code for saving these ranges as pdf.

Thanking in anticipation.

Warm Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: What is the formula in cell H5 ? It looks like you have a regular pattern of 45 row blocks offset by 90. Does the workbook have any protection on it ?

Comment: Screenshots of what you have and what you're hoping to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.
I have excel with 15 financial goals. The output is displayed in Sheet1 one below the other with 1st goal output displayed on $B$1:$X$45, 2nd goal on $B$46:$X$90, 3rd goal on $B$91:$X$135 and so on.
Formula used in Sheet2 cell H5 to identify which goal ranges are to be saved based on data available:
=CONCATENATE(IF(Sheet1!C1="","","$B$1:$X$45, "),IF(Sheet1!C46="","","$B$46:$X$90, "),IF(Sheet1!C91="","","$B$91:$X$135, "))
Very Sorry, my organization does not allow me to access forums and share screenshots. Hope I am able to clarify my need.

Comment: Hello, I was able to get the VBA working. The issue was with number of characters in range. As I understand max 255 characters can be used in range. With Union of range, I was able to get the VBA working